# \ref doens't output the good reference

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, auxiliary-files

I have a big `.aux` file (850 lines), which contains the line:

```
\newlabel{aumilieudesalarmes}{{6}{\pageref  {86testpage}}}
```

When I set `\ref{aumilieudesalarmes}`, I expect to see `6`.

But, in this case, i get `55`!

Does `ref` do anything other than take the value indicated in the `.aux` file?

The strangest is that, if I create a MWE, I don't have the problem....

For example:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extbook}    
%pdfLaTeX
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage[french]{babel}


\newcommand\titre{%
\vspace{1em}%
{\centering%
AMAZING POEM\par%
}%
}

\usepackage{ifthen}% provides \ifthenelse
\usepackage{xifthen}% provides \isempty test
\newcounter{NumberNote}
\setcounter{NumberNote}{0}
\newcounter{nbrefpage}
\setcounter{nbrefpage}{0}
\newcommand\note [2][]{%
    \stepcounter{nbrefpage}%
    \def\tmpnbrefpage{\arabic{nbrefpage}testpage}%
    \mbox{\label{\tmpnbrefpage}}%
    \stepcounter{NumberNote}%
    \footnote{#2}%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}%
    {%
        \customlabel{#1}{\arabic{NumberNote}}{\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}}%
    }%
}

\makeatletter%
\newcommand{\customlabel}[3]{%
\protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{#3}}}%
}%
\makeatother%


\begin{document}
see the (savant!) note~\ref{a_savant_note}, page~\pageref{a_savant_note}

\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem\note[a_simple_note]{a simple note}
I'm an amazing poem
I'm an amazing poem\note{an anoter simple note}
I'm an amazing poem
I'm an amazing poem
I'm an amazing poem
I'm an amazing poem\note{an anoter simple note}
I'm an amazing poem\note{an anoter simple note}
I'm an amazing poem
I'm an amazing poem
I'm an amazing poem\note{an anoter simple note}
I'm an amazing poem\note{an anoter simple note}
I'm an amazing poem\note[a_savant_note]{a SAVANT note}
I'm an amazing poem\note{an anoter simple note}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

makes this kind of `.aux`:

```
\relax 
\catcode `:\active 
\catcode `;\active 
\catcode `!\active 
\catcode `?\active 
\babel@aux{french}{}
\newlabel{1testpage}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{a_simple_note}{{1}{\pageref  {1testpage}}}
\newlabel{2testpage}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{3testpage}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{4testpage}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{5testpage}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{6testpage}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{7testpage}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{a_savant_note}{{7}{\pageref  {7testpage}}}
\newlabel{8testpage}{{}{1}}
```

and logically, when I call `\ref{a_savant_note}` in the example, i get the good number `7`.

I have no idea why in my real work, I can obtain a number totally different than the real written in the `.aux`...

Sorry for this question, which is perhaps too open.

**EDIT**

I have to precise that, in my real work, when I type `\ref{aumilieudesalarmes}`, I get the good page reference value, in this case `\pageref  {86testpage}`, which refers to an another label, properly evaluated.

Comment: check if you have multiple label names. The log should then contain a warning.

Comment: code that does not show the problem is not an example that is useful. Start from a copy of your real document and delete things while still showing the issue then post the result.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer thank you for your answer, but I don't have any warning about multiple label references.

Comment: Yes @DavidCarlisle, I will do that. Sorry for this post maybe posted too shortly.

Comment: But, more generally, what does `\ref` do? Does not take the value written in `.aux`?

Comment: Several packages overwrite how `\label` and `\ref` works (e.g. `hyperref`); did you happen to load one of these packages?

Comment: Sorry guys. Great thanks for your interest in my problem. But I think I solved it. The strange thing is it that a 2-compilation causes the problem, solved by a 3-compilation. Im my `xxx.sh`, I have a little script like it: 
`name="xxx"`
`pdflatex --shell-escape $name.tex`
`mv $name.pdf ... build/`
If I write two times `pdflatex --shell-escape $name.tex`, I have the strange problem. If I write 3 times it, I do not more have the problem... even though the `.aux` is identical.

Comment: So @DavidCarlisle had right... We always have to develop a full MWE... Sorry.

Comment: Yes @WillieWong , thanks for your answer, but I don't have `hyperref`.

Comment: Try replacing `\pageref` with `\getpagerefnumber` from the refcount package.